# what's going wrong in my below writing and reading in ObjectStream

Tags: java, byte, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

below code to write my objects and byte[] into file with sigBytes being my byte[]

```
ObjectOutputStream outputOS = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
    outputOS.writeInt(sigBytes.length);
    outputOS.write(sigBytes);
    outputOS.writeObject(text);
    outputOS.close();
```

then when i execute code below i get an java.io.OptionalDataException

```
ObjectInputStream inputIS = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(INPUT));
    int length = inputIS.readInt();
    byte[] sigBytes = new byte[length];
    inputIS.read(sigBytes, 0, length);
    String text = (String) inputIS.readObject();
```

Below the error I get at `String text = (String) inputIS.readObject()`:

> java.io.OptionalDataException
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
>       at encryption3.Encryption3.decrypt(Encryption3.java:34)
>       at encryption3.Encryption3.main(Encryption3.java:53)

EDIT 
i can't make the error repeat in a minimal as below??? and i'm really to tired for this..

```
public static void doThings() {

    try {
        File file = new File("C:/edges/input.ext");

        String text = "Hello";
        file.createNewFile();

        byte[] sigBytes = (text).getBytes();

        ObjectOutputStream outputOS = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        outputOS.writeInt(sigBytes.length);
        outputOS.write(sigBytes);
        outputOS.writeObject(text);

        ObjectInputStream inputIS = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        int length = inputIS.readInt();
        byte[] sigBytes2 = new byte[length];
        inputIS.read(sigBytes2, 0, length);
        String text2 = (String) inputIS.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EncryptionError.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: on which line do you get the exception? what is your reasoning about the possible cause of the exception?

Comment: (And why are you calling `writeObject` rather than `writeString`?) Can you reproduce this in a [mcve]?

Comment: ObjectOutputStream doesn't have a writeString

Comment: simple explanation: you are reading a file which wasn't produced by the write routine. As @JonSkeet already said, can you give a reproducible example? .

Comment: Ah, true - I was thinking of DataOutput.

Comment: your example runs without problems. I am tired of this too and voting to close

Comment: but i have to show this to my teacher tomorrow to pass my year

Comment: huh... wtf now it works, but i didn't change anything????? sorry guys, can close this indeed

Comment: This error may have come when you have different sequence of write and read statements.  Current code is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OptionalDataException.html)

> Exception indicating the failure of an object read operation due to unread primitive data, or the end of data belonging to a serialized object in the stream. This exception may be thrown in two cases:

1. An attempt was made to read an object when the next element in the stream is primitive data. In this case, the OptionalDataException's length field is set to the number of bytes of primitive data immediately readable from the stream, and the eof field is set to false.
2. An attempt was made to read past the end of data consumable by a class-defined readObject or readExternal method. In this case, the OptionalDataException's eof field is set to true, and the length field is set to 0.

**EDIT**: Your code is running fine in my computer too.

From your code,

You are already writing `text` as `String` object to the file with this statement:

```
outputOS.writeObject(text);
```

Below statements may not be needed to write a String by converting it into byte[] and write byte[] length + byte array.

```
outputOS.writeInt(sigBytes.length);
outputOS.write(sigBytes);
```

Comment: I realize this has been accepted, but it doesn't seem to actually explain what's going on at all...

Comment: I suspect that he had wrong sequence of writes & reads earlier before post and got the error rectified by himself after sometime.

Comment: Possibly. Not necessarily though - see my answer, which could explain things. Admittedly file-based streams *rarely* display this behaviour in my explanation, but I don't think they're *guaranteed* not to...

Answer (score 5):

I believe I understand what may be going wrong here... you're currently using `read(sigBytes)` which does *not* guarantee that it will read all the data you've requested. In general, `InputStream.read(byte[])` and `InputStream.read(byte[], int, int)` only guarantee that they will read *some* data before returning, unless the stream is closed. It's entirely possible for them to read less data than is asked for - this often happens if you're reading data over a network, for example, where the stream can return the data it has already received, but won't block forever waiting for more data to come.

If only part of your data is read, then the subsequent `readObject` call will be reading from some arbitrary point within your original data, which could easily cause an exception to be thrown as it's unlikely to be the start of a valid object representation.

In this case, I believe you want:

```
inputIS.readFully(sigBytes);
```

where [`readFully`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readFully-byte:A-) *is* guaranteed to fill the byte array, or will throw an exception if it reaches the end of the stream before completing.